# How do I extract the value from a particular cell across hundreds of .csv files?

Tags: r, loops

I have approximately 400 `.csv` files and need to take just one value from each of them (cell `B2` if opened using spreadsheet software).

Each file is an extract from a single date and is named accordingly (i.e. `extract_2017-11-01.csv`, `extract_2018-04-05`, etc.)

I know that I can do something like this to iterate over the files (correct me if I am wrong, or if there is a better way please do tell me):

```
path <- "~/csv_files"

out.file <- ""

file.names <- dir(path, pattern =".csv")

for(i in 1:length(file.names)){
  file <- read.table(file.names[i], header = TRUE, sep = ",")
  out.file <- rbind(out.file, file)
}
```

I want to effectively add something at the end of this which creates a data frame consisting of two columns: the first column will show the date (this ideally would be taken from the filename) and the second column will hold the value in cell `B2`.

How can I do this?

Comment: If you use `nrows` you can set a max number of rows to read in, and with `skip` you can skip the first line. With  `colClasses=c()` and `NULL` for the cols you want to skip you can select only the column you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This lets you select only the second row and the second column when you import:

```
extract_2018_11_26 <- read.table("csv_files/extract_2018-11-26.csv", 
                                 sep=";", header = T, nrows=1, colClasses = c("NULL", NA, "NULL"))
```

Because `nrows=1` means that we read only the first rows (except the `header`), and 
in `colClasses` you secify `"NULL"` if you want to skip a column and `NA` if you want to keep it.

Here following your code, `gsub()` lets you find a pattern and replace it in a string:

```
out.file <- data.frame()
for(i in 1:length(file.names)){
  file <- read.table(file.names[i], 
                     sep=";", header = T, nrows=1, colClasses = c("NULL", NA,"NULL"))

  date <- gsub("csv_files/extract_|.csv", "",x=file.names[i]) # extracts the date from the file name
  out.file <- rbind(out.file, data.frame(date, col=file[, 1]))
}

out.file
#         date col
# 1 2018-11-26   2
# 2 2018-11-27   2
```

Here the two `.csv` original files:

```
#first file, name: extract_2018-11-26.csv
  col1 col2 col3
1    1    2    3
2    4    5    6
#second file, name: extract_2018-11-27.csv
  col1 col2 col3
1    1    2    3
2    4    5    6
```

Answer (score 0):

data.table approach

```
#build a list with csv files you want to load
files <- list.files( path = "yourpath", pattern = ".*.csv$", full.names = TRUE )

library(data.table)
#get value from second row (skip = 1) , second column ( select = 2 ) from each csv, using `data.table::fread`... 
#bind the list together using `data.table::rbindlist`
rbindlist( lapply( files, fread, nrows = 1, skip = 1, select = 2 ) )
```

extracting the data from a filename is a different question, regex related.. please ask in a different quenstion...